# How to establish a url prefix for all $.ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an issue with $.ajax when my website has a path base where the url that I specify in javascript is missing the path base and the route is not found.  Is there a good strategy for accounting for path base with $.ajax?

I had the idea to use ajaxSetup with beforeSend to alter the url with a prefix, which would allow me to set the url prefix from a global location, instead of having to modify every url string in my code base with the prefix, but if I use beforeSend with my $.ajax call, then the beforeSend established with ajaxSetup is ignored, so I don't see how that option could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with.  I found that ajaxSend let me do what I couldn't with ajaxSetup.  Please, excuse the ASP.Net references.

```
<script>
    $(document)
        .ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {

            var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
            if (!settings.url.startsWith(baseUrl))
            {
                // need to account for instances where your website has a path base
                settings.url = baseUrl + settings.url;
            }

        })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patch it, run this code once, early on in your application, before any ajax requests (replace *http://localhost:4000* with the prefix of your choice):

```
(() => {
  let org = $.ajax;
  let prefix = 'http://localhost:4000';
  $.ajax = function (...args) {
    args[0] = prefix + args[0];
    return org.apply(this, args);
  }
})();
```